Why can't I upgrade to Gitlab Community Edition 17.0.1
I want to upgrade my Gitlab Debian edition from 16.9.1-ce to 17.0.1. Something has changed how do I upgrade.
apt-get install gitlab-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gitlab-ce is already the newest version (16.9.1-ce.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

To get this to work I had to update to the latest version of the Gitlab 16 releases.
Step 1.
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

Step 2.
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=16.11.3-ce.0

Step 3.
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=17.0.1-ce.0


You need to upgrade twice
apt-get install gitlab-ee=16.11.3-ee.0
apt-get install gitlab-ee=17.0.1-ee.0

Which version of debian are you using?
If APT isn't finding new packages maybe you can try reinstalling the apt source.
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

Otherwise you can download it manually.
https://packages.gitlab.com/app/gitlab/gitlab-ee/search?q=&filter=debs&filter=debs&dist=debian
Had similar issue with linux mint virginia not being supported, replaced with ubuntu 22.04 and now it's ok (but debian should be supported).
You can check a file, which will differ from mine
cat /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.gitlab.com_gitlab_gitlab-ee_linuxmint_dists_virginia_InRelease
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

Origin: packages.gitlab.com/empty/deb/
Label: packagecloud_generic_empty_deb_index


if it's not an empty file you should have something like /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.gitlab.com_gitlab_gitlab-ee_ubuntu_dists_jammy_main_binary-amd64_Packages which contains all the packages

I am on Community Edition. I noticed your code is asking me to install ee Enterprise Edition?

Also, I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

root@gitlab:~# dpkg -i gitlab-ce_16.11.3-ce.0_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb: error: 'gitlab-ce_16.11.3-ce.0_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive gitlab-ce_16.11.3-ce.0_amd64.deb (--install):
dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
gitlab-ce_16.11.3-ce.0_amd64.deb

Yes sorry my mistake, see that you posted procedure for community edition and it's all good now :).
